# url rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

so my first page is index, then from index i call a page called vetements where i include a get variable called cat wich is the category of wear, then when im on vetements page i call a sub category(here i stay on vetements page(the page redraws itsel with php) the problem is im unable to combine this 2 rules in htaccess

my links should look like:

```
vetements-Robes-Robes-courte
```

vetements is the name of the page itself

Robes is category

Robes-courte is sub category

right now this rule works when im on page vetements:

```
RewriteRule ^vetements-(.*)-(.*-.*)      /vetements.php?cat=$1&sous_cat=$2  [L]
```

but it wont work when i go from index to vetements, to make it work from index to vetements i have to do the following:

```
  RewriteRule ^vetements-(.*)-?(.*-.*)?
```

but then it wont work in vetements(when i redraw the page to call the sub category)

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

maybe try a rewerite like this:

```
RewriteRule vetements-cat-(.*)-sous_cat-(.*)\.htm$ vetements.php?cat=$1&sous_cat=$
```

this is what was suggested by http://www.webconfs.com/url-rewrite-tool.php

You might also want to look at other tutorials and examples on creating so-called "search-friendly URLs" since that's essentially what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Does your index page have vetements-Robes-Robes-courte  in the link to vetements page?

Comment: the index calls vetements like this: <a href="vetements-<?php echo $hRow["category_name"]; ?>"> , to answer your question: no, because the sub category is not yet known it happens in vetements